# Exportar datos de consulta a formato CSV desde la consola de MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en `MySQL`, con la cual obtengo los posts asociados a los usuarios que los han creado

```
SELECT users.nameUser, posts.namePost
FROM users
JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id;
```

Sin embargo necesito trabajar directamente desde la consola y al tiempo que ejecuto dicha consulta necesito exportar el resultado de la misma a un archivo externo en formato `.csv`; se que existen entornos visuales como Heidi o como Workbench para hacer esa tarea de manera rapida pero yo necesito trabajar desde la consola;

**¿cómo logro hacer dicha tarea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nivel de la consola de `MySQL`, podemos ejecutar la consola de la siguiente manera para exportar los datos a un formato de un archivo externo

```
SELECT users.nameUser, posts.namePost INTO OUTFILE 'C:/respaldo.csv'
FROM users
JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id;
```

Lo que estamos haciendo es:

> 1. La sentencia `INTO OUTFILE` hace un volcado de la tabla a través de la sentencia `SQL` a un archivo determinado que se va a crear en
>      ese momento
> 2. El valor que va entre las comillas, es la ruta absoluta a donde estas apuntando que se cree el archivo que va a contener el resultado
>      de tu consulta `SQL`, debes revisar el nombre del archivo y la
>      extensión del mismo para que la creación se haga sin problema
> 3. La sentencia `INTO OUTFILE` debe ir justo antes del `FROM` que indica la primer tabla de donde hace referencia dicha consulta